# Regular Expression for City, State in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I would require a regular expression for testing a textbox for City, State.

The valid examples are:
Dallas,TX
Dallas, TX
Dallas,Texas

I tried `/([^,]),\s*(\w{2})/`. It is not covering up all cases

Can anyone help me out in this. Thanks!

Comment: I tried /([^,]),\s*(\w{2})/ . It is not covering up all cases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
var re = /^[A-Za-z]+,[ ]?[A-Za-z]+{2,}$/;
// Use `re.test("City,State");` to get true/false
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/E3HCk/

All this does is requires the string start with at least one alpha character, followed by a comma, then an optional space, then at least two alpha characters.

Answer (score 1):

After trying Lan's version, i found the following works for me.

```
\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+,[ ]?[A-Z]{2}\b
```

I found most of the state is upper case and two characters as well as the upper case on the first letter of the city.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful..

```
^.*\, ?[a-zA-Z]*
```